# Function works fine, until it is within an IF statement

Tags: php, symfony

Using one of my controllers, the code works fine when it is not in an IF statement however when it is placed within one it does not add the required data (notification_id) into the db.

Code:

```
public function devicesUidDataFunctionAction($id)
{
    if (isset($_GET['notification_id'])) {

        $notification_id = $this->getRequest()->get('notification_id');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();       
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $q = $query->update('AppBundle:Users', 'z')
        ->set('z.notification_id', '?1')
        ->where('z.id = ?2')
        ->setParameter(1, $notification_id)
        ->setParameter(2, $id)
        ->getQuery();
        $p = $q->execute();

        return new Response("", 200, array("content-type"=>"text/html"));
    }
    else {

        $lat = $this->getRequest()->get('location[lat]', null, true);
        $lng = $this->getRequest()->get('location[lng]', null, true);
        $acc = $this->getRequest()->get('location[accuracy]', null, true);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();       
        $query1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $q = $query1->update('AppBundle:Users', 'z')
        ->set('z.lat', '?1')
        ->set('z.lng', '?2')
        ->set('z.acc', '?3')
        ->where('z.id = ?4')
        ->setParameter(1, $lat)
        ->setParameter(2, $lng)
        ->setParameter(3, $acc)
        ->setParameter(4, $id)
        ->getQuery();
        $p = $q->execute();

        return new Response("", 200, array("content-type"=>"text/html"));
    }
}
```

The ELSE part of the code works flawlessly when within the ELSE statement it is just the first half I am having issues with. It does return the 200 OK but nothing is added into the DB.

**EDIT - More information**

This is the URL coming into the controller:

```
http://[WEBSITE]/devices/135/data.json?notification_id=123456
```

And originates from an Android application with the following in the logcat:

```
Sending using 'POST' - URI: http://[WEBSITE]/devices/135/data.json - parameters: {notification_id=123456, hardware_attributes[ram_size]=694}
```

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the function actually enters the "if" section of the block?

Comment: Just did a quick test and it seems to be missing the IF block and going straight to the ELSE, not sure why this is.

Comment: The "if" condition is not evaluating to "true". Without any other context, it's hard to guess why that might be.

Comment: If it works with `$this->getRequest()->get('notification_id')` you should use that in the condition as well and not access the `$_GET` variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the parameter you are checking is not in the querystring but it is being sent as part of the POST?

To check if this is true you can try to substitute

```
if (isset($_GET['notification_id'])) {
```

with

```
if (isset(**$_POST**['notification_id'])) {
```

Consider also that you should be accessing the $_GET and $_POST informations with these instructions:

```
// $_GET parameters
$request->query->get('name');

// $_POST parameters
$request->request->get('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your if condition is never satisfied, hence code after it is not executed. Because in symfony we use [Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object to fetch GET, POST and other HTTP info.

e.g. to fetch a GET param we use `$this->getRequest()->query->get('paramName');`

so you should be checking like this:

```
if(isset($this->getRequest()->query->get('notification_id')) {
  //your stuff
}
```

**EDIT:**
Please also note  $this->getRequest() method its deprecated now Instead inject Request class object into your controller and use it.

e.g.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;



public function someAction(Request $request)
{
 $id = $request->query->get('notification_id');

}
```